# Send email report with HTML file attached using node js after the run is complete using protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, email-attachments, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer for email sending in my code. I want to run it after my test cases have been executed by protractor. Right now, it is mailing me the old HTML file that I have in my directory before the run gets completed.

I also tried using EmailJS, but got to the same result.

I want it to run after my test gets completed and report is generated, so that I receive the latest report.

Answer (score 2):

Place your mail send script in the `onComplete` function in the protractor.conf.js file.

```
var mailer = require(/* Mail module */);

exports.config = {
    // Other config...

    onComplete: function () {
        // Send mail...
    }
};
```